# Error with building application in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm new to Android, my IDE is Android Studio, in the gradle sync window I see 2 errors:

> Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
>   Install Repository and sync project
> Show in File
> Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Error:(23, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0
>   Install Repository and sync project
> Show in File
> Show in Project Structure dialog

I tried downloading support library from SDK Manager but unfortunately I could not because we are under limitation because I'm in Iran.

Then I downloaded it manually and added it to my project/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar and I added it to gradle.build in dependencies line

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.aqil.textview"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('support/annotations/android-support-annotations.jar')
    compile files('support/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('support/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
    compile files('support/customtabs/libs/android-support-customtabs.jar')
    compile files('support/design/libs/android-support-design.jar')
    compile files('support/multidex/library/libs/android-support-multidex.jar')
    compile files('support/multidex/instrumentation/libs/android-support-multidex-instrumentation.jar')
    compile files('support/percent/libs/android-support-percent.jar')
    compile files('support/recommendation/libs/android-support-recommendation.jar')
    compile files('support/v13/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('support/v14/preference/libs/android-support-v14-preference.jar')
    compile files('support/v17/leanback/libs/android-support-v17-leanback.jar')
    compile files('support/v17/preference-leanback/libs/android-support-v17-preference-leanback.jar')
    compile files('support/v4/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
    compile files('support/v7/cardview/libs/android-support-v7-cardview.jar')
    compile files('support/v7/gridlayout/libs/android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar')
    compile files('support/v7/mediarouter/libs/android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar')
    compile files('support/v7/palette/libs/android-support-v7-palette.jar')
    compile files('support/v7/preference/libs/android-support-v7-preference.jar')
    compile files('support/v7/recyclerview/libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
}
```

But when I try to build my project, I get this error

```
   Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+ as no versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 are available.
     Required by:
         TextView_Programming_API17:app:unspecified
```

I'm using API 17 and I tried 19,20,25 but the error is same. Also I added Support library repository, but didn't work, where is the problem?

Comment: Can you access this link from your browser? https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-compat/24.2.0/support-compat-24.2.0.aar

Comment: @KamranAhmed i get this error "The requested path was not found."

Comment: Updated the link, can you now?

Comment: i downloaded it now,ok now what i have to do with it?im asking is it ok to use it with my current min API 17?

Comment: @KamranAhmed can you contact me on telegram?@aqilhex

Comment: Which version of the support lib have you downloaded? Try to set the exact version instead of the `+` like `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

Comment: @Eselfar now i get this error when i hover compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1  "Dependency on a support library, but the SDK installation does not have the "Extras > Android Support Repository" installed. Open the SDK manager and install it." less...

Comment: '25.3.1' is the version number of the support lib you want to use. It needs to be the same as the one you have manually downloaded. If you have downloaded the '25.3.0' for example, set 25.3.0' instead of 25.3.1'

Comment: @Eselfar are you sure its not refer to my build tools?so how can i check which version of support library i have?because it wasnt mention which version it is

Comment: Yes I think so. On Windows the lib is here:
[RootOfTheSDLFolder]\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\[libVersion(e.g.25.3.1)]. You said you're on Linux so I don't know but I guess it's similar

Comment: Hum... Maybe @star_hex is right on a point, it seems that you've put the lib in the lib directory of your project (`compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')`) so I'm not sure on how to manage that. I'd suggest to put your library in the folder I'm talking about above. Or if you leave it here maybe remove `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'` as the system tries to get the library from the web source if not in the Android folder

Comment: i tried all this things but didnt works

Answer (score 1):

just try to use VPN , u can use hotSpotshield app for solving this limitation

Comment: i tried but didnt work,im using tor in linux,if you know any other way to do it,suggest me

Answer (score 0):

From these three lines remove the first line

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')}

Only use last two lines

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')}

Because you can't define same file more than one time.
Hope this solution helps.

Comment: Uninstall android support repository from sdk manager
Install again android support repository , and then clean your project and rebuilt it

Answer (score 0):

You support repositories seem to be old. You need to:

- Open SDK Manager by click on this button

[image: SDK Manager Button]

- Switch to *SDK Tools* tab

[image: SDK Tools Tab]

- Check *Android Support Repository*
- Click *Apply*

This should update your repository and the versions you are trying to access should be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add Google's Maven repository to your project's Gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        //...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i added this before, but didnt work, here is my gradle i edited it in the question.check it